# Evaluating $\iint_D \sqrt{4x^2-y^2}\;\ \mathrm dx \ \mathrm dy$ steps

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to evaluate

$\displaystyle\iint_Df(x,y)\;dxdy$ for $f(x,y) = \sqrt{4x^2-y^2}$

with $D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq x\}$.

I know that there ([Evaluating $\iint_D \sqrt{4x^2-y^2}\;\ \mathrm dx \ \mathrm dy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/581803)) is exactly same problem already marked as solved, but I do not understeand the solution. Could somebody explain  the steps of integrating this kind, please?

Thanks

Edit: Gave it a try with recommended substitution and did not really work out. Evaluated in wolfram, because I am not very familiar with hyperbolics. I am not sure about the limits:
$\displaystyle\int^{\frac{log(3)}{2}}_0 \int^{\frac{2}{cosh(ϕ)}}_0 \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3cosh^3(ϕ)}dr dϕ$

I know that the result should be $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\pi}{9}$ and this result converged to ±0.45 and correct result should be ±0.63, also more interested in steps, than number.

Comment: *"but I do not understeand the solution"* Could you please indicate and quote exactly what you don't understand about the solution, and why?

Comment: Just about everything in sktech, after first row, starting with 4(x^2/...), because I am not familiar with that type of substitution/process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Make the substitution $$(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{2}r\cosh(\theta ), r\sinh(\theta )\right)$$

Comment: Will give it a try! I guess it is not random, so how did you think of this substitution?

Comment: Becose it's an hyperbola, and thus hyperbolic function seem to be a good substitution.